# Polygon with large XML set of points

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map that I built 4 years ago with API v2. I'm now trying to upgrade it to API v3, but all I get is the infamous blank gray box where the map should be. I have done console.log all over the place and all the data and variables look correct to me, but I am not a Google Maps expert.

Here is the map in it's current broken state:
https://www.idahopower.com/AboutUs/serviceMap/

The map is supposed to show 4 shaded polygons representing my company's service area divided into regions. The points that make up the polygon borders come from a large XML file (1573 lines) on my server, which is here:
https://www.idahopower.com/AboutUs/serviceMap/serviceMap.xml

I am not sure if I am doing this in the best way, but I am using XMLHttpRequest() to load the XML data.

This was all working with API v2. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I get an error: GET https://www.idahopower.com/vlb/jquery.min.map 404 (Not Found) /vlb/jquery.min.map:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not initialize the map correctly (center and zoom are required [MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapOptions)):

```
// Create map object
//
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"));
```

from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HelloWorld)

```
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
```

[working example, your code with center and zoom set](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_xmlPolygon.html)

Comment: Although it's not  
sufficient to successfully draw a map, it is valid syntax(the documentation marks the 2nd argument as optional).

Comment: Thanks, fixed the wording.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your Polygon, you didn't set the required options `zoom` and `center` for the map.

Related to the XML: 1500 vertices isn't that much, but when you want to improve the performance you may send the data as JSON(it should reduce the amount of data to the half)